# uWSGI workers can't find python module gevent

Tags: python, python-2.7, uwsgi, importerror, gevent

I have a daemon that prints the following errors.

```
...
Respawned uWSGI worker 58 (new pid: 23363)
DAMN ! worker 59 (pid: 23300) died :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 59 (new pid: 23364)
DAMN ! worker 60 (pid: 23301) died :( trying respawn ...
ImportError: No module named gevent
ImportError: No module named gevent
Respawned uWSGI worker 60 (new pid: 23365)
...
```

`gevent` seems to be install because there is a folder in `/usr/lib/local/python2.7/site-packages/`.

I'm using Kronos from Locu https://github.com/Locu/chronology/tree/master/kronos
Running Kronos from the .py file works though, so the problem doesn't seem to be related to Kronos. Why aren't uWSGI workers able to find the package?
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and providing path to virtualenv solved the issue.

Specify the path to virtualenv

```
-H /path/to/your/virtualenv
```